# How to pass a variable between function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So this program lets me make a customizable stick figure. I'm pretty new to python and this is my first big project outside of school computer science. Since the coordinates for the body arms end at different places, I need the coordinates from the bodyfunc,short,medium and long. This program works but for some reason it's not getting the value and passing it the my tail/ accessory function. Can you look at my program please and help me!

```
import turtle


#Head
def headfunc(headtype, headcolor, headpensize):
    head=turtle.Turtle()
    head.color(headcolor)
    head.pensize(headpensize)
    if headtype=="square":
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        head.penup()
        head.left(90)
        head.forward(200)
        head.pendown()
        head.left(90)
        head.forward(50)
        head.right(90)
        head.forward(100)
        head.right(90)
        head.forward(100)
        head.right(90)
        head.forward(100)
        head.right(90)
        head.forward(50)

    elif headtype=="round":
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        head.penup()
        head.left(90)
        head.forward(200)
        head.right(90)
        head.pendown()
        head.circle(50)

    elif headtype=="diamond":
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        head.penup()
        head.goto(0,200)
        head.pendown()
        head.goto(35,300)
        head.goto(0,400)
        head.goto(-35,300)
        head.goto(0,200)

    else:
        print("Not valid")
# Body
def bodyfunc(bodytype,bodycolor, bodypensize, endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y):
    body=turtle.Turtle()
    body.color(bodycolor)
    body.pensize(bodypensize)
    if bodytype=="short":
        bodylength = 200
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        body.penup()
        body.goto(0,200)
        body.pendown()
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)  #Body Length
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body(Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4)  #Arm Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4) #Arm Length (Left)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/4, 200-3*bodylength/2) #Leg Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/4,200-3*bodylength/2)#Leg Length(Left)
        endbody = 200-bodylength
        endarm_x = bodylength/2
        endarm_y = 200-bodylength/4
        return endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y

    elif bodytype=="medium":
        bodylength = 300
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        body.penup()
        body.goto(0,200)
        body.pendown()
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)  #Body Length
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body(Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4)  #Arm Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4) #Arm Length (Left)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/4,200-3*bodylength/2) #Leg Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/4,200-3*bodylength/2)#Leg Length(Left)
        endbody = 200-bodylength
        endarm_x = bodylength/2
        endarm_y = 200-bodylength/4
        return endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y

    elif bodytype=="long":
        bodylength = 400
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        body.penup()
        body.goto(0,200)
        body.pendown()
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)  #Body Length
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body(Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4)  #Arm Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/2,200-bodylength/4) #Arm Length (Left)
        body.goto(0,200-3*bodylength/8)                       #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(bodylength/4,200-3*bodylength/2) #Leg Length (Right)
        body.goto(0,200-bodylength)                      #Body (Reposition)
        body.goto(-bodylength/4,200-3*bodylength/2)#Leg Length(Left)
        endbody = 200-bodylength
        endarm_x = bodylength/2
        endarm_y = 200-bodylength/4
        return endbody

    else:
        print("Not valid")
# Tail
def tailfunc(tail, endbody):
    if tail=="yes":
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        tail=turtle.Turtle()
        tail.penup()
        print(endbody)
        tail.goto(0,endbody)
        tail.pendown()
        tail.color("brown")
        tail.right(65)
        tail.circle(60,200)
        tail.shape("triangle")

    elif tail=="no":
        quiterty=1

    else:
        print("Not valid")

def accessories1func(accessories1, endarm_x, endarm_y):
    a=turtle.Turtle()
    if accessories1=="sword":
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        a.goto(endarm_x, endarm_y)
        a.forward(100)
        wn.mainloop()


def main():
    headtype=input("Enter head(square,round,diamond)")
    headcolor=input("Head Color?:Red,white,black,gray,brown,gold,purple,blue,cyan")
    headpensize=input("Head pensize? 1-5")
    bodytype=input("Enter body(short,medium,long")
    bodycolor=input("Body Color?:Red,white,black,gray,brown,gold,purple,blue,cyan")
    bodypensize=input("Head pensize? 1-5")
    tail=input("Tail: Yes or no")
    accessories1=input("sword,staff,gun,bow")

    endbody = 0
    endarm_x = 0
    endarm_y = 0

    headfunc(headtype,headcolor, headpensize)
    bodyfunc(bodytype,bodycolor, bodypensize, endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y)
    tailfunc(tail,endbody)
    accessories1func(accessories1, endarm_x, endarm_y)

main()
```

Comment: Could you reduce this a bit?  There is too much code here.

Comment: Don't post your entire program and just ask for "help". Tell us *exactly* what's wrong, and post only the code necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: A slightly belated welcome to SO.  You will get better help here if you make it _easy_ to help you.  Please read  the http://stackoverflow.com/help and http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow, i'll make sure to make things easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not capture the return values.  You need to do something like:

```
endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y = bodyfunc(bodytype,bodycolor, bodypensize, endbody, endarm_x, endarm_y)
```

but it looks like your return type from `bodyfunc` is not consistent so this might give you other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be best served by creating a class.

```
class stickfigure(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.headtype=input("Enter head(square,round,diamond)")
    self.headcolor=input("Head Color?:Red,white,black,gray,brown,gold,purple,blue,cyan")
    # you get the idea.
```

This way, the values you want to preserve are members of each stick figure you create.